# I want to update Checkbox(Custom Field) on Contact whenever a new Opportunity is created based on Contact in (Primary_Contact__c)

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, trigger-oldmap

I want to update Custom Field(Checkbox) on Contact whenever a new Opp is created and Opp has Primary Contact from Contact

```
trigger PrimaryConOnAccOfOppHandler on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete) 
{
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        PrimaryConOnAccOfOppHandler.insertHandler(Trigger.New);
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete)
    {
        PrimaryConOnAccOfOppHandler.deleteHandler(Trigger.Old);
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        PrimaryConOnAccOfOppHandler.updateHandler(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
}
```

```
public class PrimaryConOnAccOfOppHandler 
{
    //New Opportunity is Created
    public static void insertHandler(List<Opportunity> newOppList)
    {
        Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity opp : newOppList){
            conIds.add(opp.Primary_Contact__c);
        }
        List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
        for(Contact a : [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIds]){
                    a.Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c=true;
                    conList.add(a);
        }
        Update conList;
    }
    //Old Opportunity is Deleted
    public static void deleteHandler(List<Opportunity> oldOppList)
    {
        Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity opp : oldOppList){
            conIds.add(opp.Primary_Contact__c);
        }
        List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
        List<Opportunity> opptList = [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact__c FROM Opportunity WHERE ContactId IN :conIds];
        if(!opptList.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Contact a : [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIds]){
                a.Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c=True;
                conList.add(a);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(Contact a : [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIds])
            {
                a.Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c=False;
                conList.add(a);
            }
        }
        Update conList;
    }
    //Old Opportunity is Updated
    public static void updateHandler(List<Opportunity> oppList, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOppList)
    {
        Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity opp : oppList){
            if(opp.Primary_Contact__c != oldOppList.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c )
            {
                conIds.add(opp.Primary_Contact__c);
            }   
        }
        List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
        List<Opportunity> opptList = [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact__c FROM Opportunity WHERE ContactId IN :conIds];
        if(!opptList.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Contact a : [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIds]){
                a.Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c=True;
                conList.add(a);
            }
        }
        else{
            for(Contact a : [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIds]){
                a.Primary_Contact_Checkbox__c=False;
                conList.add(a);
            }
        }
        Update conList;
    }

}
```

Now Insert and Delete is working Fine but Problem lies in Update Section..I don't want this to perform Bulk Operations.

I want to perform same operation as written in code but i think my Condition is Wrong.. Can someone guide me here?

Comment: How is `Primary_Contact__c` populated? It sounds like it's just not populated at the time of the `after insert` trigger.

Comment: calling 'insertHandler' method from which DML context ?  `after insert` or 'before insert'?

Comment: ```after Insert``` and I've made some changes in the Code

Comment: We can't confirm whether your code is correct, Manish. I'd suggest writing unit tests to validate its behavior; that and hands-on testing are the best safeguard.

Comment: Can you Please check Update Conditions where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use triggers?

This functionality is available via process builder and it takes round 5 min to build a process that will cover your requirement.

If it is a bit more complex you may use even flow which is triggered from process. And this covers a lot of use cases.